# Cannot reach .NETCore API on IIS

Tags: angular, iis, .net-core, production-environment

I've been working on an angular / .NETCore 3.1 Api application.
It's working just fine in visual studio.

But when I publish it to IIS on a server, I cannot reach the api.
The request returns the home page html page instead.

It's like every url returns index.html

I must be missing some config in the routing.
I'm not sure if I should look in my app configuration (Startup.cs) or IIS configuration.

-------- EDIT ----------

@samwu

I write my reply in the original post since code does not fit very well in comment.

My controllers have the following attributes.
Like I said, it works just fine on dev. My problem occurs on production server.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

And here is my startup.cs with my default route.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3(options =>
        {
            options.Path = "/swagger";
        });


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {               
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
          </handlers>
          <aspNetCore processPath=".\WebApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
       </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 41534ce7-c9b2-4c11-9cba-3a81af6e8ef0-->
```

Comment: Can you show me your default route on startup.cs and web.config file in iis?

Answer (score 0):

you must be add the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
        <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebDAV" />
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\{{your_App}}.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The web.config was already there. It was missing the webdavmodule configuration. though I don't think this is related to my issue, I have tried adding it but still same behavior.

Comment: @julien plase verify the `applicationUrl` in launchSettings.json

Comment: according to MS documentation  _The launchSettings.json file:

Is only used on the local development machine_.([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1#development-and-launchsettingsjson]). I'm having trouble making it work on production server.